# Extra "?>" symbol in PHP file (top left corner)

Tags: php, jquery, html, post, symbols

I have an issue with a PHP page which displays a "?>" symbol in the top left corner. It looks like this:

```
<?php 

include_once("DBconnect.php");

$getuser = $_POST["RegUsername"];
$getpass = $_POST["Pass"];
$getrepass = $_POST["RePass"];
$getemail = $_POST["Email"];

if($getuser){
    if($getpass){
        if($getrepass){
            if($getpass == $getrepass){
                if($getemail){
                    $code = rand();
                    if(mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$getuser', '$getpass', '$getemail', '0', '$code')")){
                        echo "INFO1";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "ERROR6";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    echo "ERROR5";
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "ERROR4";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "ERROR3";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "ERROR2";
    }
}
else{
    echo "ERROR1";
}

?>
```

And I use this jQuery function to display the PHP returned value in my HTML page:

```
$("#RegSubmit").click(function(){
    $.post( $("#RegForm").attr("action"),
            $("#RegForm :input").serializeArray(),
            function(info){
                $("#RegErrorLog").empty();
                $("#RegErrorLog").html(info);
            }); 

    $("#RegForm").submit(function(){
        return false;
    });
});
```

I always get the "?>" in front of the PHP "ERROR" returned value.
How can I get rid of that? Or how can I return a value from the PHP file using a variable instead of `echo`

Comment: try creating new php file.

Comment: What's in the DBConnect.php file?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it's extremely important: implement SQL sanitization. Your code as it stands could allow attackers to easily manipulate your database or even delete every record within it. This thread is a very apt discussion on the importance of SQL sanitization: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there's a problem in your *DBconnect.php* file.

Apart from that... you should really think about validating values taken from Http POSTs in your PHP script, before using them in db queries.

Comment: It was my DBconnect.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are not printing that symbol on the included file "DBconnect.php".